# Отображение ячейки в QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Как в Qt сделать так, чтобы ячейка в QTableWidget хранила какое-то значение, но при этом отображала другую информацию, значение которой зависит от хранимой информации в ячейке? Грубо говоря, ячейка с индексом (1:1) (cell[1][1]) хранит значение типа int, например число 7, а отображает строку типа QString "test_cell".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Испольуйте `QTableWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)`

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
item->setText("text");
item->setData(Qt::UserRole, 42);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,item);
```

Будет выведен текст `text`, а в качестве данных в ячейке будет лежать 42. В одну ячейку можно положить несколько пользовательских переменных, используя в качестве `role` `Qt:UserRole + 1`, `Qt:UserRole + 2` и т.д.

Взять данные из ячейки:

```
QVariant v = item->data(Qt::UserRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно установить свой делегат через setItemDelegate и в нем реализовать отображение всего что душе угодно, например подменяя в методе paint значение QStyleOptionViewItem::text на свое. Но тогда надо еще обрабатывать setEditorData и setModelData чтобы корректно преобразовывалось значение перед началом и после окончания редактирования в ячейке.

Comment: Я, собственно, этим и занимаюсь. Написал свой комбобокс, унаследовав от ComboBoxItemDelegate. https://wiki.qt.io/Combo_Boxes_in_Item_Views

Comment: в void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData(...) через model->setData устанавливаю необходимое значение. Я правильно понимаю, что мне необходимо сразу после выполнения этой инструкции "перерисовать ячейку"?

Comment: Не до конца понятно, про какой именно метод paint вы имеете ввиду, метод какого класса? просто я не могу найти его ни у QTableWidget ни у QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Речь о `QAbstractItemDelegate::paint`. Если все сделано правильно, ничего перерисовывать не нужно. Оно само вызовет paint. А вот внутри него уже можно подменить text на свой и передать измененные данные в базовый класс.

Comment: Примерно вот так: `QStyleOptionViewItem my_option = option;
    my_option.text = "my text";
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,my_option,index);`